# Javascript Interface not working

Tags: java, android

I am new to android Programming. I have some problems with using Javascript Interface. The code doesn't show any errors but  nothing happens when running the code. Can anyone help? This is my code:

**LINES IN ONCREATE**

```
 public String BaseURL = "http://192.168.1.101/test/";
 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 WebSettings mWebViewSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
 mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
 mWebViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
 mWebView.loadUrl(BaseURL + "index.php");
```

**WEB APP INTERFACE**

```
 public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAndroidDialog(String dialogMsg){
        Toast.makeText(mContext,dialogMsg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="Trigger Dialog" onClick="showAndroidDialogg('test')" />


<script type="text/javascript">
  function showAndroidDialogg(dialogmsg) {
    Android.showAndroidDialog(dialogmsg);
}
</script>
```